# Add Progress Bar C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I'm trying to add a progress bar into my program.

```
FileLoadPB.Maximum = mainClass.values.realXPos.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < mainClass.values.realXPos.Count; ++i)
{
    FileLoadPB.Value += i;
    ComponentList.Items.Add(new MappedPoint { pointNum = i + 1, xPoint = mainClass.values.realXPos[i], yPoint = mainClass.values.realYPos[i] });
}
```

I want the FileLoadPB progress bar to increment by 'i' each time an object is added to my ListView. This works, however it doesn't actually show the progression of the bar. It only shows empty at the start of the loop, and full and the end. I've read a few things on BackgroundWorker, however I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Your problem ist, that the UI thread is blocked during the execution of the loop. Consider using a backgroundworker

Comment: I put that I've read up on BackgroundWorker, I just don't know how to implement it in this case.

Comment: super easy tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

Comment: Sorry I must admit I didn't read `til the end. I posted a dummy example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code is just a dummy to illustrate how to use the BackgroundWorker. Hope it helps

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    List<int> listDummy = new List<int>();

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
    }

    void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        var numberOfItems = 111;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            listDummy.Add(i);
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((double)i / numberOfItems * 100));
        }
    }

    void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I saw somebody doing this in WPF, we'd have a serious talk about his career prospects.